# Problem with prestashop hook.php and tab.php files

Tags: prestashop

We got an error at the top of some pages:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/classes/Hook.php on line 491.

I've read that it could be a problem with the foreach loop or arrays, but I don't know php and don't know how to fix it.

In line 491 I find: foreach ($results as $result) {

Another problem is that when I enter a category from the client side, I can't go to the 2nd/3rd/4th/5th page, only one page is displayed and the next ones don't want to load. The error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/classes/Hook.php on line 491 appears on pages that do not want to load.

I also get an error after enabling debug mode:
PrestaShopBundle\EntityTab.
The association PrestaShopBundle\EntityTab#tabLangs refers to the owning side field PrestaShopBundle\EntityTabLang#tab which does not exist.

I changed:

- @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PrestaShopBundle\Entity\TabLang", mappedBy="tab")
  to
- @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PrestaShopBundle\Entity\TabLang", mappedBy="id")

insrc/PrestaShopBundle/Entity/Tab.php but it doesn't help.

[PHP debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEd2O.png) [debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ehB0.png)

Comment: It's needed more info. Please do this: in Hook.php, just before line 491, write this: `if (!is_array($results)) die(var_export($results, true) . Db::getInstance()->getMessageError());`. Then visit the page, and when it get blank,, copy all shown text and add it to your question. Also you can contact me at https://josecarlosphp.com

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem - I had to change active to m.active in the body of the sql query. Thank you